# How can i select an Html.Radiobutton according to the object value

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, radio-button

i have the folloiwng RadioButtons inside my asp.net mvc Edit view:-

```
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.InsuranceSettled)
</div>

<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.RadioButton("InsuranceSettled", 1) Yes
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.InsuranceSettled)
</div>

<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.RadioButton("InsuranceSettled", 0) No
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.InsuranceSettled)
</div>
```

But how i can select the desired radio button accoring to the Model values , so if the model.InsuranceSettled value is 0 then to select the No radio button and visa versa ..
BR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using `RadioButtonFor` instead. I think it's always best to use the strongly typed helpers to generate your inputs to guarantee your inputs have the correct names. Also they'll automatically choose default values based on your model.

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.InsuranceSettled, 1) 

@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.InsuranceSettled, 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
@Html.RadioButton("InsuranceSettled", 1, Model.InsuranceSettled == 1)
....
@Html.RadioButton("InsuranceSettled", 0, Model.InsuranceSettled == 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.InsuranceSettled , "True", model.InsuranceSettled == 1? new { Checked = "checked" } : null)

@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.InsuranceSettled , "False", model.InsuranceSettled == 0? new { Checked = "checked" } : null)
```